# Binding DataGridView and SQL Table

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I am new with this so i think it will be easy for you.I am making WFA application.I have DataGridView on my form and i want to insert SQL table in DataGridView.Here is my code:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        OracleDataReader reader;
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        cmd.CommandText = "select * from rezervacija where korisnicko_ime_posetioca = '" + kip + "'";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

        }
```

I already opened the connection so thats not a problem.What do i need to do while reader is reading so i could bind data's?

Comment: Don't use inline SQL like in the manner you are doing it, use parameterized SQL to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Please look at this page:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`OracleDataAdapter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter.aspx) like this:

```
OracleDataAdapter yourAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter();
OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand("select * from rezervacija where korisnicko_ime_posetioca = :kip", conn);

//Add your parameters like this to avoid Sql Injection attacks
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(":kip", kip);
yourAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
DataSet yourDataSet = new DataSet("RezervacijaData");

yourAdapter.Fill(yourDataSet, "rezervacija");

//Finally do the binding

yourDataGrid.SetDataBinding(yourDataSet, "Rezervacija");
```

This is the general idea. I'm not at my development machine so I haven't tested the code, but it should be fairly close.